# how to configure selenium cucumber framework in GitLab pipeline using gitlab-ci.yml configuration file

Tags: selenium, configuration, cucumber, pipeline, gitlab-ci.yml

I facing the below error while running the selenium cucumber project in GitLab pipeline, using .gitlab-ci.yml configuration

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Samplemaven: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:Samplemaven:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:7.2.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:7.2.3: Could not transfer artifact io.cucumber:cucumber-java:pom:7.2.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To run selenium cucumber project in GitLab, we need to setup this .gitlab-ci.yml file under the root folder. Use the below configuration in .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
image: maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile


test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pwd
    - mvn test
```

Makes sure you have used the below plugin in pom.xml file,

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/RunCukes*.java</include><!-- specify your runner file here -->
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: While running the pom.xml as maven test in your local IDE it should trigger the cucumber runner file